# I need a clear understanding of React's Strict and Fragment method

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a toggle functionality on my Todo list. Below are two different results when running the code (without changing my code) in the strict and fragment method.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD3EO.jpg)

[Result in fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZLpf.jpg)

[Result in strict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68uxv.jpg)

As you can see, the first result worked as expected when the button is clicked several times, but in strict mode, it keeps returning the same output.

Could anyone explain what is happening?

Thank you for sparing your time :)

Comment: Provide the code in stackoverflow code snippet, or any live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: You are mutating state in ACTIONS.TOGGLE_TODO.